# Connect to Azure Database for MySQL without having to specify @host on user

Tags: mysql, azure, system-administration

I'm deploying a legacy application that uses MySQL using Azure Database for MySQL. The thing is that the connection string is hardcoded into the application and i dont have access to the source code either but i do know the user and password that it uses to connect to the database.

I tried to connect it to my database on azure using iptables to redirect the traffic from the legacy application target ip to my azure instance ip, but i'm having a problem with the username since the leacy app does not specify a host in the user name and even if it did i have no way to change it.

I managed to connect it by creating a local instance of mysql(with the user and password that the legacy application uses) and using the Federated Engine to access the Azure Database, but it is too slow and i need another alternative.

So my question is, Is there any faster way to connect my application to the Azure Database?

Comment: What is this supposed to mean? "does not specify a host in the user name" Do you mean "does not specify a host in the connection string"?

Comment: @silent - the OP is referring to the Azure SQL connection string, where the username includes `@hostname` in it (and it sounds like their legacy app doesn't support this, due to a hardcoded username). If I had to guess, they have some hardcoded username, which they re-created within a hosted Azure MySQL instance, but they can't connect because they cannot append `@hostname` to the username, within the embedded connection string.

Comment: @DavidMakogon That is exactly the problem